# Regex: how to select <td> of the location with PHP

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Html code:

```
<div username="bob">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>alex</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>location</td>
                    <td>London</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>123</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div username="apple">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>david</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>id</td>
                    <td>321</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div username="pepper">
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>location</td>
                    <td>Bradford</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I want to select the location by username.
for example:
bob location = London,
apple location = return false,
pepper location = Bradford
I want to get with regex.

Comment: Why does the user, with the username of 'bob', have 'alex' as the specified name? And how are these tables being constructed, surely you have a reference to the location when you're creating them?

Comment: Have you tried something to do this? [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I only want to select by username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div\s+username="pepper">(?:(?!<\/div>)[\s\S])*?location.*?\s+<td>([^<]*)
```

Try this.Change names as per your needs.See demo.Grab the capture or group.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/67

```
$re = "/<div\\s+username=\"pepper\">(?:(?!<\\/div>)[\\s\\S])*?location.*?\\s+<td>([^<]*)/i";
$str = "<div username=\"bob\">\n <table>\n <tr>\n <td>name</td>\n <td>alex</td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td>location</td>\n <td>London</td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td>id</td>\n <td>123</td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n </div>\n\n <div username=\"apple\">\n <table>\n <tr>\n <td>name</td>\n <td>david</td>\n </tr>\n <tr>\n <td>id</td>\n <td>321</td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n </div>\n\n <div username=\"pepper\">\n <table>\n <tr>\n <td>location</td>\n <td>Bradford</td>\n </tr>\n </table>\n </div>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```